# What is the right way to capture panics?

Tags: error-handling, rust

Frequently we don't want our program stopping due to out of bounds, division by 0 or similar panics. However, `std::thread::catch_panic` is marked us unstable. We could write...

```
let result = Thread::scoped(move || {
        make_a_division_for_ever()
    }).join();
    if result.is_ok() {
        println!("Finished OK");
    }
```

Is this the right way to capture panics (like division by 0 or out of bounds)?

A complete example...

```
use std::thread::Thread;

fn main() {
    println!("Make divisions for ever");

    loop {
        let result = Thread::scoped(move || {
            make_a_division_for_ever()
        }).join();
        if result.is_ok() {
            println!("Finished OK");
        }
        else {
            println!("It CRASHED!!!  restarting...");
        }
    }

}

fn make_a_division_for_ever() {
    loop {
        println!("Enter divisor...");
        let line = std::io::stdin()
                .read_line()
                .ok()
                .expect("error reading line");

        let divisor = line.trim()
                .parse::<u32>()
                .expect("
I coudn't parse your line as an string. I'm going to die
I showed things closer than orion belt...
        ");

        println!("readed {}", divisor);

        let dangerous =  1_000_000 / divisor;

        println!("DIV RESULT... {}", dangerous);
    }
}
```

Comment: The right way is not to panic in the first place but to use proper error handling, returning errors and that sort of thing.

Comment: This is great, but it's easy to forget verifying an integer division. And it is easy to get a panic for out of bounds accessing elements in a vector with [ ]. Those are a couple of examples. Rust do a great job on compiling checking, but it doesn't force us to verify bounds on vector access (when using '[ ]' neither force verification on integer division.

Comment: Division error or out of bounds accesses are logical errors and should be fixed. I understand that it may be inconvenient that the program aborts but in C(++) it would crash anyway.

Comment: That's something I don't like in C++. C++ has a lot of undefined behaviour and crashes. I like the idea of a compiler checking and warning about possible dangling pointers, null pointers, unchecked access, etc... In C++ I work with a wrapper of stl containers in order to avoid undefined behaviour with iterators.

Answer (score 7):

Rust panics aren't intended to be caught in most cases. Unstable Rust provides this functionality, but you should only be using it if you have a really complex situation (say, you're writing a test harness for other Rust programs and need to hook into the panic handler) where you can't bubble up the error.

In Rust, error handling is done by returning [`Result<T,E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/result/enum.Result.html)s (sometimes `Option<T>`, bubbling them up with `try!()`, and handling them with `match`.

Most panicky methods have non-panicky versions; for example a checked version of divide is [`checked_div()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.u8.html#method.checked_div), and you can use `try!` to return the errors from the string parsing.

Comment: I like the Resutl, Option, and try! error control, but you can write code not compabible with it.  

Even more, in some cases, it's easier to write code producing panics than code with error control.  

A couple of examples is division and out of bounds in vector.  

It's easier to make a division with operator / than calling checked_div.  

It's easier to call my_vector[n] than  my_vector.as_slice.get(2).And compiler don't warn you.  

as_slice is marked unstable... Unstable: waiting on RFC revision

Comment: Again, as @PEEP pointed out in the OP comments, if you have a unintended division by zero or out of bounds access, you have a logic error in your program, which you must correct.

Comment: I absolutly agree. In C++ a dangling pointer a race condition accessing to some data, etc... are also program logic errors and they have to be fixed. But I don't like when the program stops or crash due to a logic error.

Comment: @JoseLuis `my_vector.as_slice().get(2)` can be written simply as `my_vector.get(2)` due to autoderef. `as_slice()` itself can always be replaced by `[..]`, i.e. `my_vector[..][2]`.

Panics in a single threaded program should always indicate bugs OR a wanted crash.

Panics in a multithreaded program additionally can be used to bring a thread down (intentionally). Don't use them for C++-style exception handling; Rust isn't designed for that.

Comment: If you treat Rust as if it's C++ and program with the same paradigms; stuff isn't going to work.

Comment: @Manishearth  thanks for your answer.  That's the point. I don't want to work with Rust as I do in C++, but I want to avoid program stopping due to simple errors on it. I like Rust avoiding dangling pointers, null pointers, race condicions, etc... I just want to know what's the right way to deal with these kind of errors that generate panics and program stopping.

Comment: @JoseLuis You should use the non panicky versions of the API. Yes, in some cases it's more verbose, but the choice of verbosity is usually made in situations where a failure is almost always indicative of a bug.

Comment: Also, there's not many other ways to structure the `/` operator -- would you have it output NaN? What about integer division? It would be much, much worse to output an `Option`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I think that, if it's critical to avoid program stopping, creating a thread is the way to avoid it and deal with potential program defects which could throw a panic and stop the hole program.