Capturing Rust generated panic as C++ exception
I'm testing Rust libraries which may panic, using them in C++ code. I have the following library:
Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "boom"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"

[lib]
crate-type=["staticlib"]

src/lib.rs:
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn boom() {
    panic!("Oh no, something went wrong!");    
}

I'm building it using cargo build and using the result in the following C++ code (boom.cpp file):
// g++ -g boom.cpp -L./target/debug -lboom -o boom

extern "C" {
    void boom();
}

int main() {
    boom();
}

The result is:
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at src/lib.rs:3:5:
Oh no, something went wrong!
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5

So far so good.
I'm trying to capture that panic into my C++ code. I have tried the following:
// g++ -g boom.cpp -L./target/debug -lboom -o boom

#include <stdexcept>

extern "C" {
    void boom();
}

int main() {
    try
    {
      boom();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
      printf("exception captured\n");
    }
}

but the result is the same instead of the expected exception captured message.
Is there any way in C++ code to capture the panic generated at Rust library? Or, the other way around, is there any way of transforming a Rust panic into a C++ capturable exception?

"I'm testing Rust libraries which may panic" Is this absolutely insurmountable? Panics are not intended to be captured like C++ exceptions are. The closest mechanism to recoverable errors in Rust are in functions returning a Result<T, E>. Relevant reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232890/what-is-the-right-way-to-capture-panics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824258/recovering-from-panic-in-another-thread

from what I read by skimming over https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-01-unrecoverable-errors-with-panic.html panics are NOT exceptions -- they aren't meant to be caught.

@E_net4 thanks for your feedback! Beyond the simplified examples in my question above, I'm afraid that the real Rust library I'm using (https://github.com/mozilla/jexl-rs) is working that way and panics in some circumstances (instead of returning proper errors). So the motivation of my question.

@ChristianStieber thanks for the feedback! I understand that panic aren't meant to be caught but in this case I have no option (except forking and modifying a library not implemented by me, which is hard, see comment above). As far as I know, Rust provides some mechanism to capture panics (panic::catch_unwind, as seen here) but I don't know how to use that to generate a C++ exception to be captured in my C++ program using the Rust library (if possible)

A library which tends to panic on certain inputs is either a sign of a bug or a poorly designed API. Given that the library in question is open source, it does not seem farfetched to send a contribution where it's due. Otherwise, you would need an extra layer of input sanitization. There's catch_unwind as a last resort. Then the second part of the question, which I believe is more interesting, is how to turn a Rust error into a C++ exception.

Keep in mind that I have never used Rust, but what about https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html ? This wouldn't throw an exception, but you could probably call some function in your C++ code with the "PanicInfo"... while I'm not sure whether this could even be made to return your original calling frame, I would try to throw from inside that hook function just to see what happens...

Rust declares letting a panic escape through an FFI boundary to be undefined behavior. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77876748/when-is-a-panic-on-a-rust-ffi-boundary-undefined-behavior

As Sebastian notes you can't panic through an FFI boundaries, FFIs speak C (or really platform ABIs), and even if they did (windows' might support SEH) I don't believe Rust uses that for panics. So what you should do if you can't get the upstream to fix panics and can't fix you own code to avoid triggering them is std::panic::catch_unwind in the extern and return a safe error code or structured error.

For mixing Rust and C++, I'd set panic = 'abort' in your Cargo.toml.  A panic is not an exception.

I just had a quick look through the jexl source code (https://docs.rs/jexl-parser/0.2.2/src/jexl_parser/lib.rs.html and https://docs.rs/jexl-eval/0.2.2/src/jexl_eval/lib.rs.html) and AFAICT it only panics in tests. And the public functions are documented as returning Error, not panicking…

@Jmb thanks for your feedback! You are right: after a careful examination, the jexl-rs library is behaving correct... it's a wrapper library of my own between jexl-rs and my C++ program the one that wasn't. Thus, I'll modify my library to use the Result<T, E> pattern taking into account the valuable feedback provided in this post.

C has no exception
There is no C++ FFI for Rust, but only a C FFI.
There is no exception in C, and therefore no specified ABI for exception propagation.
As a result, there is no standard mechanism to propagate an exception from Rust to C (or C to Rust), which wouldn't help much since there's no way to interact with exceptions in C anyway.
Exceptions should not cross language boundaries
There is no specific in Rust here, either. Letting C++ exceptions cross C stack frames is already a gamble.
In either case, C stack frames do not generate any code for handling unwinding, and therefore perform no clean-up when unwound during exception propagation, resulting in Undefined Behavior. In practice, the consequences are anything from "just works" to "leaky" to "corrupted state".
Unless explicit compatibility is guaranteed by the toolchain, exceptions should not cross language boundaries.
So how to handle Rust panics in C++?
By translating them, manually or automatically, at the FFI boundary.
That is, from Rust to C++:

On the Rust side, use catch_unwind to translate the exception into an error.
On the C++ side, handle the error (possibly throwing again).

And if you forget, hopefully RFC 2945 will save you (by aborting) as you're experiencing.
From C++ to Rust:

On the C++ side, use catch to translate the exception into an error.
On the Rust side, handle the error (possibly panicking again).

And if you forget, you have formally entered Undefined Behavior land. Good luck.
